# C++ Weird char printing behavior

Tags: c++

I tried to write a piece of code that ask you to type a certain key on your keyboard (random) to train typing. Like so:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  string numbers = "1234567890";                              // 0 -> 9
  string letters = "azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbn";              // 10 -> 35
  string letters_upp = "AZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN";          // 36 -> 61
  string letters_acc = "éèàçù";                               // 62 -> 67
  string symbols = "&'(-_ç)=#{[|`^@]}°+$£%*µ,?;.:/!§<>€\"\\"; //
  //
  string keybord = numbers + letters + letters_upp + letters_acc + symbols;
  //
  srand(time(NULL));
  int index = rand() % keybord.size() - 1;
  char search = keybord[index];

  bool program_launched = true;
  string rst;

  while (program_launched) {
    cout << "Please enter : " << search
         << " to go further (Enter 'quit' to quit)."
         << endl;

    cin >> rst;

    if (rst == "quit") {
      cout << "The char was : " << index << endl;
      program_launched = false;
    } else if (rst[0] == search) {
      index = rand() % keybord.size() - 1;
      search = keybord[index];
      cout << "Good answer !" << endl << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Wrong answer !" << endl << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that some char aren't properly printed in the terminal for example this could happen:

> Please enter : � to go further (Enter 'quit' to quit).

I tried to print the entire string char by char to see which one was problematic:

```
for(int i = 0; i < keybord.size(); i++){
     cout << keybord[i] << endl;
}
```

The output was:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
a
z
e
r
t
y
u
i
o
p
q
s
d
f
g
h
j
k
l
m
w
x
c
v
b
n
A
Z
E
R
T
Y
U
I
O
P
Q
S
D
F
G
H
J
K
L
M
W
X
C
V
B
N
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
�
&
�
�
'
(
-
�
�
_
�
�
�
�
)
=
#
{
[
|
`
^
@
]
}
�
�
+
$
�
�
%
*
�
�
,
?
;
.
:
/
!
�
�
<
>
�
�
�
"
\
```

But when I deleted the `<< endl` for a better visibility this happened:

```
1234567890azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBNéèàçù&é'(-è_çà)=#{[|`^@]}°+$£%*µ,?;.:/!§<>€"\
```

Which means that the `<< endl` somehow makes the char weird in the terminal. I'm using UTF8 btw. (Defining `string keyboard` by adding other strings isn't the problem from what I experimented)

Do you know what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: what does " I'm using UTF8 btw." mean?

Comment: Unfortunately, `std::string` is not Unicode aware. It works with bytes rather than codepoints.

Comment: My file is encoded with UTF8 format

Comment: @pm100: I believe that means, "I am using UTF-8, by the way."

Comment: I'm using Linux subsystem for windows.

Comment: `string` -> `wstring`; `char` -> `wchar_t`; `cout` -> `wcout`; `"..."` -> `L"..."`

Comment: Why do you subtract 1 after the mod? If the mod operation returns 0, you will get undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user17732522: No, that is not it. Just a different set of problems. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the code below you have a chance to get the value `-1`:

```cpp
int index = rand() % keybord.size() - 1;
```

So sometimes you get an Undefined Behavior.

But the difference in the output with and without `std::endl` is explained with the multi-byte encoding. You may observe that some of the characters are represented with 2 "weird symbols". If you output them without interruption with the newline, you would see the Unicode symbol instead.